# What are these containers called?

Tags: terminology, technical, image-identification, tech-writing

The german term is *Absetzmulde* ([Image search](https://www.google.de/search?q=absetzmulde&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFiObVwovMAhXIlSwKHdTjBlsQ_AUIBygB&biw=1528&bih=887)).

They look like this:
[image]
*Image source: [Sirch GmbH](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiI5NjtwovMAhVFliwKHWhWAs0QFggpMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sirch.com%2Fcontainerbau%2Fabsetzmulden%2F&usg=AFQjCNEkBcg9Ie_THSPk_67YkJEFtLLfSw&cad=rja)*
There are varios different styles of bulk goods containers that can be easily loaded on/off a truck, but I'm specifically looking for this shape.

Comment: In the US, large metal containers for refuse are called *dumpsters*. But many are of different shapes from the one illustrated.

Comment: I've voted to move this question to English Language Learners, where it will help more people. I've given you a +1 to get you off to a good start over there :)

Comment: Yeah, generally a "dumpster" (from a trade name) in the US, also just "bin" and the like at times.  ("Skip" is apt to get you dumb looks.)

Comment: @HotLicks Depends where in the world you are. In British English, "dumpster" doesn't exist, "bin" means "trash can" and describing the object in the question as anything other than a skip will get you strange looks.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - Hence I qualified my comment with "in the US".

Comment: I'll note that the above "dumpster" is the angular style that would typically be used (in the US) for (de)construction debris -- the one for ordinary garbage or office waste would be more rectangular (and likely painted dark green).  But, except perhaps within the waste industry, there don't tend to be special names based on the type of waste.

Comment: A dumpster which is dropped off at a location, filled, then picked up and taken away is called a 'rolloff', as opposed to a standard dumpster, which is left in a location, and a truck picks it up and dumps the contents then puts it back down.

Comment: This style of dumpster is normally used only for heavy waste (metal recycling) and if not called a dumpster or _material_ dumpster it is called a heavy dumpster (allowing heavy loads)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's called a ***skip*** in British English. It may have other names in other dialects.

> *British* A large transportable open-topped container for building and other refuse:
>   *I’ve salvaged a carpet from a skip*
>
> [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skip#nav2)]

A [Google image search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=skip&newwindow=1&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyzaqlxIvMAhWllIMKHTUqAgUQ_AUIBygB&biw=1440&bih=773) yields lots of examples.

Comment: Funny: I've image searched quite a few terms *except* skip because at a former job we reffered to roll on/off dumpsters as skips. Germans and our english!

Comment: Right, a skip is generally a trash receptacle.  It doesn't have to be, but that's the first thing that will come to mind. Those are called portable hoppers

Comment: Skip was the first thing I thought of when I saw the picture.

Comment: It's generally called the same thing in Australian English as well.

Comment: So I rang up a local building firm. I said "I want a skip outside my house." He said "I'm not stopping you."

Comment: American English speaker, here. I've never heard this term :( Just an FYI, depending on who you're communicating with. I would actually just call it a container, or dumpster, depending on how it's being used. Dumpster typically implies garbage, but it's not strict with that usage.